What process node enabled the 6502 to reach 2 MHz?
The original version of the 6502 was rated for 1 MHz, but before the end of the decade, the CPU was available in a 2 MHz version. Presumably what changed was Dennard scaling: make the transistors smaller, they switch faster.
What exactly was the process node that enabled the 6502 to reach 2 MHz?

The answer could be easy. Can you point to a specific data sheet of a 6502 from some manufacturer that goes to 2 MHz? Also do you mean end of the '70s or the '80s just to be sure.

The assumption in the question is wrong. From the very beginning there was a 2MHz version: https://web.archive.org/web/20221029042234if_/http://archive.6502.org/datasheets/mos_6500_mpu_preliminary_may_1976.pdf

Although that partly sidesteps the question, 6502 was made using an 8um process, which presumably was the key to 2MHz operation if you were lucky

@lvd Oh, good find, thanks! I guess they were all made with the same 8um process, test them at 2 MHz, then the ones that fail, try them again at 1 MHz.
